# Spark (pyspark) how to reduceByKey on only 2 element of a tuple of 3 element

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, tuples

I have the result of map that looks like this

> [ ('success', '', 1), ('success', '', 1), ('error',
>   'something_random', 1), ('error','something_random', 1), ('error',
>   'something_random', 1) ]

Is there a way with a reduce by key to endup as:

> [ ('success', 2), ('error', 3) ]

and then somehow print on a file all the errors ?

Answer (score 6):

Here are two options to get the result you need:

1) convert the 3 element tuple to 2 element tuple then use `reduceByKey`:

```py
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2])).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
# [('success', 2), ('error', 3)]
```

2) `groupBy` the first element of tuple, then sum up the values (third element) for each group using `mapValues`:

```py
rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x[0]).mapValues(lambda g: sum(x for _,_,x in g)).collect()
# [('success', 2), ('error', 3)]
```